Why is hard disk making noises (only) after running rsync with no processes accessing disk?
When running a rsync command with grsync the hard drive makes noise despite that it's not being accessed. I don't see anything writing or reading from disks a lot in KDE's System Monitor or KDE's System Activity process manager or with sudo htop when sorting by column IO_RATE. I also don't see anything accessing the disk when running sudo lsof | grep /media/veracrypt1/. Grsync and rsync are not running.
How to see what's causing these noises or what's causing disk activity? I suspect it may have to do with either some integrity checks due to the file changes, journald or with ksystemstats but I'm not sure at all. Going to standby and resuming or dismounting and then remounting the veracrypt-encrypted partition also only silences it for a short time. I basically need a reliable way to check what's causing this sound. It's not a very loud sound but it's all the time and a bit annoying.
It must be the hard drive: it sounds like it and when I put it into standby with the Gnome DiskUtility it goes silent and it gets noisy again when I turn it on again (for example when saving a modified file to that disk). This only occurs after using rsync, not at any other times.

what kind of hard disk is it (mechanical size, computer interface and server/desktop/laptop/archival/CCTV market?), and how old is it?

Pretty new SMR HDD.

oh, so this is a backup / archival disk?

I'm looking for a way to see actual read-write. Currently not even a music player accesses the disk but it still makes these sounds so something is going on with the disk.

It was making noises even after reboot but it turned quiet later. A strange thing is that it stays quiet when putting the disk in standby (and it stays in standby). Pretty sure this will occur again after whenever I run rsync again.

Maybe the drive firmware is programmed to start doing self-tests or some internal maintenance when powered up and idle for a certain time? smartctl -l xselftest,selftest /dev/sdX might indicate if the disk /dev/sdX is running self-tests.

oh, @telcoM has a valid point. some SMR disks might have a non-shingled region on the disk, which they use as write cache, and which they might regularly try to move to a shingled section (for which they might need to check what's on there). I don't know whether that applies to your disk, though.
